# Send mail with laravel using mail function php

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I use mail php function for sending mail with laravel.
My route:

```
Route::post('/mailsend', 'Home@contact');
```

My controller:

```
public function contact(Request $request){

        $to = 'contact@email.com';
        $from = $request->input('email');
        $subject = $request->input('subject');
        $message = $request->input('message');
        $headers = 'From: '.$from . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: '.$from . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


        return view('contact');
    }
```

my problem, I can't get my values input in post

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because you likely forgot to include the CSRF token in the form that submits to that page.

Make sure to include it like this :

```
<form method="POST>
  <!-- ... -->

  {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```